# uncaught syntaxerror; unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, token

I get error on chrome console :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Seems to be about syntax error but I can't find anything wrong.
it is just sign of beginning php codes but how can it makes syntax error on this case??

```
some other codes above

            <!--Map below -->

<div id="mgmap"></div><br />
<br />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&language=en&region=us&key=myGoogleMapKeyHere"></script>

<script src="<?=$board_skin_url?>/markerclusterer.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var ymakcur;
var ymakcurOptions = {styles:[{
    height: 53,
    width: 52,
    url: '<?=$board_skin_url?>/img/ymc2.png',
    }],gridSize: 20, maxZoom: 17};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var ymypoint = '<?php echo $board_skin_url ?>/img/mapicon002.png';

var address = new Array(
    <? for ($i=0; $i<count($list); $i++) {   <--- **in this line < makes the error**
    $ylat=($list[$i][wr_3]);
    $ylng=($list[$i][wr_4]);
    ?>
    "<?=$ylat?>,<?=$ylng?>"
    <? if ($i==count($list)-1) continue; ?>
    ,
    <? } ?>
);

some other codes below
```

Comment: `<?` != `<?=` - careful with your [opening tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). Since you don't want to echo, you should probably use a full `<?php` tag.

Comment: your $list not declare

Comment: Perhaps you have short_tags disabled.

Comment: I changed to full <?php tag in all of them. thanks @Lewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<?` which is a short open tag of PHP, you have to enable it.

Set `short_open_tag=On` in your `php.ini` and restart the server.

Of course, using this type of opening tag is not recommended.
Look at [PSDR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md). In the overview section, the first line.

Comment: not recommended... so I chose to use full tag. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your php.ini file.
2. Search for short_open_tag
3. update short_open_tag= on